# D3 assign colors to specific series

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to assign two colors to two series in my data so that when I sort ascending or descending, the colors remain the same for each group.

The data is pulled programmatically from web map features. I thought I could get away with using an alternating function to assign colors but this doesn't work if I use sorting. I am trying to find a proper way to assign colors specifically to the series.

The data I am using has OL and NOL as two groups. You can see below how it is structured.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/p1pfhat8/)

relevant code:

```
var values = feature.properties;              
var data = [
    {name:"N11OL",value:values["N11OL"]},
    {name:"N11NOL",value:values["N11NOL"]},
    {name:"N21OL",value:values["N21OL"]},
    {name:"N21NOL",value:values["N21NOL"]},
    {name:"N22OL",value:values["N22OL"]},
    {name:"N22NOL",value:values["N22NOL"]},
    {name:"N23OL",value:values["N23OL"]},
    {name:"N23NOL",value:values["N23NOL"]},
    {name:"N31_33OL",value:values["N31_33OL"]},
    {name:"N31_33NOL",value:values["N31_33NOL"]},
    {name:"N41OL",value:values["N41OL"]},
    {name:"N41NOL",value:values["N41NOL"]}
];

var Colors =  ["#a6cee3", "#1f78b4"]

var margin = {top: 40, right: 2, bottom: 30, left: 180},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 575 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    barHeight = height / data.length;

// Scale for X axis
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.value;})])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["NAICS11", "NAICS21", "NAICS22", "NAICS23", "NAICS31-33", "NAICS41"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height]);

//y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .outerTickSize(0);

var svg = d3.select(div).select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .classed("chart", true);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);})
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return Colors[i % 2]; }) //Alternate colors
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "14px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

 svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", width/7)
  .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Employment by industry " + "(Total OL: " + feature.properties.IndOLTot + ")");
```

Comment: is the series determined by the name? such that N11OL is part of the OL series and N41NOL is part of the NOL series?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am having troubling to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at Line 241 in your jsFiddle

```
  bar.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);})
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            if(d.name.indexOf("NOL") > -1) {
                //return Colors[0];
                return "red";
            } else {
                //return Colors[1];
                return "black";
            } 
        }) //Alternate colors
        .attr("height", barHeight - 1);
```

This checks the name property for the substring "NOL". If the name contains "NOL" it uses the first color, if "NOL" is not found it uses the second color for a fill.

(I'm under the assumption that the series is determined by the name)

Comment: Beautiful, it works. Can you give more details on .indexOf and > -1, I am not sure I understand these parts. Thank you!

Comment: Take look at the following MDN documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf myString.indexOf(substring) will return -1 if the substring is NOT found. it will return the position of the substring within the given string

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!